# How to expand color in ListView row?

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got to this stage of a simple app, and am kind of stuck. I'm trying to make a ListView with rows, and I want to make the rows clickable, so then whenever you click on an entry, it will take you to a new screen. I've noticed whenever I've added a button to a row however, that the row's color suddenly shrinks, and I cannot expand the color to fill the whole row back up again. I've tried the Expanded() widget with the flex property, but that did not do anything at all. Here is the piece of the code that I need help with, and a picture of the problem.

```dart
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.push(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => const NewScreen(),
                  ),
                );
              },
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                height: 100.0,
                child: const Center(
                  child: Text('Entry B'),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

As you can see, the yellow color has shrinked to a box, and you can see the button behind the row. I need the yellow to fully fill the row, as picture 2 shows.

[image]

Picture 2: You may see it better here. Again, I would like the yellow color to look like the other 3 (which do not have a button assigned to them yet

[image]

I've tried the Expanded() widget, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the correct use-case of `ElevatedButton`. You shouldn't use `ElevatedButton` here. You can make use of `InkWell` or `GestureDetector` along with `Container` (just to get your color) instead of `ElevatedButton`. `ElevatedButton` should be preferred to use when you have an actual button. In your case, it's just a clickable UI Element.

Hence, you can use the following code:

```
InkWell(
    onTap: (){
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const NewScreen(),
        ),
      );
    },
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      height: 100.0,
      width: MediaQuery.sizeOf(context).width,
      child: const Center(
        child: Text('Entry B'),
      ),
    ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

`ElevatedButton` has it self style property in which you can specify the color for the button like this:

```dart
ElevatedButton(
                    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.push(
                        context,
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const NewScreen(),
                        ),
                      );
                    },
                    child: const Center(
                      child: Text('Entry B'),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

There is 2 ways that you can do your task, using `ElevatedButton` or using `Container`.

#### Example for `ElevatedButton`

```
Expanded(
  child: ElevatedButton(
    style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(),
      elevation: 0,
      backgroundColor: Colors.yellow,
      maximumSize: const Size.fromHeight(100),
    ),
    onPressed: () {
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const NewScreen(),
        ),
      );
    },
    child: const Text('Entry B'),
  ),
),
```

#### Example for `Container`

```
Expanded(
  child: InkWell( // or `GestureDetector`
    onTap: (){
      Navigator.push(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (context) => const NewScreen(),
        ),
      );
    },
    child: Container(
      color: Colors.yellow,
      height: 100.0,
      child: const Center(
        child: Text('Entry B'),
      ),
    ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).